# Can program execution go different by choosing between Enhanced for loop and old fashioned index based loop for a collection?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

I was asked this in an interview. I said no. Interviewer did not seem impressed.

Any corner case I missed?

Note: I am not talking about cases where one can iterate two times faster/modify the loop variable.

in other words any difference between

```
for (int i = 0;i<set.size();i++)
{
// do something
}
```

and

```
for (int x : set)
{
// do something.
}
```

Anything with performance(I know they both compile to same code)/etc.

Comment: Presumably you mean int i = 0?

Comment: Your title is talking about collections, yet your code shows an array. An array is not a Collection.

Comment: @Kayaman, yes, my question is for Collections. It was to highlight that I am not looking for answers which say you can modify loop vairable / iterate different number of times.

Comment: Then why does your code show an array being iterated over? An array is not a `Collection`, they're different things.

Comment: @Kayaman, modified the code.

Comment: I have given my answer below.

Comment: The question required some cleanups (collections/arrays, the starting index etc). But apart from that, I don't understand the downvotes and closing votes. The crucial difference of the iterator being created at the beginning of the loop (and keeping a reference to the collection or array it is iterating over) may be worth pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: Yes, the program may behave differently.

Kayaman already mentioned thread-safety in his answer. This is a special case that may show the different behavior. The question whether or not the collection *itself* is modified during the iteration is one aspect that may influence the program flow.

But regardless of that, with the enhanced for-loop, the iterator is created at the beginning of the loop. And this iterator will keep a reference to "his" collection that he is iterating over. In contrast to that, the iteration with the classical for-loop will take into account when the collection is replaced by a new one.

This can be seen in the following example.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DifferentForLoops
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DifferentForLoops d = new DifferentForLoops();
        d.startOld();
        d.startNew();
    }

    private List<Integer> list;

    private void createList(int size)
    {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }

    public void startOld()
    {
        createList(10);

        for (int i = 0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Old: Entry "+list.get(i)+" of "+list);
            pause();

            list = list.subList(0, list.size()-1);
        }        
    }

    public void startNew()
    {
        createList(10);

        for (int a : list)
        {
            System.out.println("New: Entry "+a+" of "+list);
            pause();

            list = list.subList(0, list.size()-1);
        }        
    }

    private static void pause()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes suppose you have for loop like

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){ 
// you manipulate i value and increase or decrease
i++;


 //  i--;



}
```

will effect for loop iteration, that is next time it will take lates i's value.
but in for each loop

```
for(int i: somearray){ 


  // you manipulate i's value.
i++;
// its not going to effect the iteration suppose somearray has length of 5 it iterate 5 times

}
```

Comment: I should have made my question clear. The loop variable won't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

In a standard (i.e. one defined in the JDK) indexed `Collection`, there would be no difference. However, `Iterator` doesn't define an iteration order, so you could have an `Iterator` that travels the collection backwards, whereas the for loop would travel forwards (i.e. from index 0 to size-1).

`Iterators` can also have different functionality when multithreading is involved, so a thread-safe `Iterator` might give a consistent view of the collection, whereas iterating with a for-loop might give undefined results.

Mostly though I'm sure the interviewer expected something more than just "no" as the answer, so that was probably the main reason he wasn't satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

enhanced for loop is to iterate your list one by one where in old for loop you may loop by jumping like

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i+=4){ 
}
```

but if you are going to read one by one, both are same even enhanced for loop is more readable and small and sweet.

Comment: Like I said, I am not talking about cases where I can iterate 2 times faster. Essentially, the iteration would be 1 item at a time.

Comment: than both cases are same